# Whats the meaning of mexican expresions

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, méxico, hispanoamérica

Whats the meaning of these Mexican expresions?

> te me vas !!!
>
> nadie me va a agarrar de su puerquito !

I heared it in a spanish telenovela but i did not understand what they mean.

Comment: Welcome to this site Moe. Please, take the [tour](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/tour) (and probably a look to the [help](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help) section). This site is a little bit different to other forums. To succeed as a learning resource we must encourage that people attempt to translate their sentences, and we help correcting (we don't want to be just a translating service). Also, in order for other user's to benefit of the knowledge of your question, multiple questions should be posted as such (separated). Thanks and welcome again.

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE! These are good questions, but we need to limit ourselves to one question per post, so this should be two separate posts. Also, we want you to do some research, and ask when you get stuck. What is your best guess on the meaning of these phrases?  What, specifically, confuses you about them?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not mexican but I can help.

*te me vas* it's also a way to say *lárgate* or *vete*. Those are *leave, get out,* etc.
As for the second one, that's also a way for saying *nadie me va a tratar como una mascota*, and that can mean *nobody's gonna make me his/her pet — nobody's gonna treat me like a pet.*

Comment: I'd never heard someone say *te me vas* before (I always hear/use *te vas **de** mí*), but I'm going to use it as an example now in my classes of the oddity of object pronoun order since a Google search shows it relatively common.  While you'd say *tú te me vas* for "you leave me", to say "I leave you" is *yo te me voy* (the *te me* must always go in that order, regardless their function).

Comment: @guifa Yes, *te me vas* is widely used.

Comment: @guifa no solo "te me vas" es un imperativo ampliamente usado en latinoamérica sino que "te vas de mi" es la primera vez que la veo en el contexto de "vete/lárgate".  "Te vas de mi" suena a una canción o poema en donde el significado es "me dejas / me abandonas" que es completamente diferente al significado del imperativo.